# How to use SCNNode filters with ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, metal, arkit

I am trying to implement a custom CIFilter to use with an SCNNode in my ARSCNView. Unfortunately it just creates a gray rectangle where the node should be on the screen. I have also tried built-in CIFilters to double check my code to no avail.

On some other SO post I have read that CIFilter only works when OpenGL is selected as the renderingAPI for the SCNView because CoreImage doesn't play well with Metal and as far as I can tell it is impossible to get ARSCNView to run with OpenGL. The said post is from 2016 so I am wondering if anything has changed.

What I am trying to implement is to outline/highlight the object on the screen to feedback the user about object selection. I have achieved something usable by adding a shader modifier but it gives limited control over shading. I really don't want to overtake all shading on myself.

Below is my CIKernel for outlining which works very good on Quartz Composer.

Any help and information is highly appreciated.

```
kernel vec4 outline(sampler src) {
  vec2 texturePos = destCoord();
  float alpha = 4.0f * sample(src, texturePos).a;
  float thickness = 5.0f;

  alpha -= sample(src, texturePos + vec2(thickness, 0.0f)).a;
  alpha -= sample(src, texturePos + vec2(-thickness, 0.0f)).a;
  alpha -= sample(src, texturePos + vec2(0.0f, thickness)).a;
  alpha -= sample(src, texturePos + vec2(0.0f, -thickness)).a;

  if (alpha > 0.9f) {
      vec4 resultCol = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, alpha);
      return resultCol;
  }else{
      vec4 resultCol = sample(src, texturePos);
      return resultCol;
  }
}
```

Comment: Any progress on this ?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I also faced a similar problem. The cause is because we made the following settings. CIFilter could be implemented by removing this setting.
I have not analyzed the details but if it comes to help!

```
sceneView.antialiasingMode = .multisampling4X
sceneView.contentScaleFactor = 1.3
```